# Storing Buffers in decodeAudioData callback method

Tags: javascript, callback, web-audio-api

I wanna make a little Browser App, that's able to play different notes. Therefor I have the sounds as Base64 encoded js-Variables.
Now I have to decode the Base64 first an then the mp3 format to make the sound available to the App.
Furthermore I have a datastructure called 'scale' which stores a simple c-Major scale like this:

```
scale = {
 'c': {
  color: 'red',
  name: 'C1'
 },
 'd': {
  color: 'darkorange',
  name: 'D1'
 },...
```

With the help of goolge and some tutorials I then do this to do the encoding:

```
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var context = new AudioContext();

    for (var note in scale){
        var cNote  = MIDI["Soundfont"]["acoustic_grand_piano"][scale[note].name];
        if(cNote){
            var byteArray = Base64Binary.decodeArrayBuffer(cNote);
            context.decodeAudioData(byteArray, storeNote, function(err) { console.log("err(decodeAudioData): "+err); });    
        }
    }

    function storeNote(buffer){
        scale[note].buffer = buffer;
    }
```

Obviously the call inside storeNote doenst work correctly, because note is always the same. I'd like to have something like storeNote(buffer, note). However I can just use a callback-Function in decodeAudioData with no additional parameters but 'buffer'.
Now the question is: How can I hand over the current note as a variable to storeNote() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            context.decodeAudioData(byteArray, function(buffer).bind(cNote){
                scale[this].buffer = buffer;
            },
```

Comment: With the following syntactical fix it works:

            context.decodeAudioData(byteArray, function(buffer){
                scale[this].buffer = buffer;
            }.bind(note),

Answer (score 1):

You could move `decodeAudioData` into your `storeNote` function and pass your note as an argument. Like this:

```
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        var context = new AudioContext();

        for (var note in scale){
            storeNote(note)    
        }

        function storeNote(note){
            var cNote  = MIDI["Soundfont"]["acoustic_grand_piano"][scale[note].name];
            if(cNote){
                var byteArray = Base64Binary.decodeArrayBuffer(cNote);
                context.decodeAudioData(byteArray, function(buffer){
                    scale[note].buffer = buffer;
                }, 
                function(err) {         
                    console.log("err(decodeAudioData): "+err); });    
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: I've done that. But it doesnt work.As a result the same buffer is stored for all notes. That's because of the asynchronous call of the inner function. At the time this function is called 'note' will not change anymore (the for-loop is already done)